Эмуляция нажатия кнопки в ЕИС закупок
Уважаемые специалисты! Я пытаюсь эмулировать в VBA нажатие изображения на странице ЕИС закупок
https://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/contract/search/results.html?searchString=%D0%BF%D0%B0&morphology=on&search-filter=%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5+%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F&fz44=on&contractStageList_0=on&contractStageList_1=on&contractStageList_2=on&contractStageList_3=on&contractStageList=0%2C1%2C2%2C3&budgetLevelsIdNameHidden=%7B%7D&sortBy=UPDATE_DATE&pageNumber=1&sortDirection=false&recordsPerPage=_10&showLotsInfoHidden=false, позволяющей произвести выгрузку контрактов (стрелочка с подчеркиванием и всплывающими словами Выгрузить результаты поиска). К сожалению мне это не удается. Прошу помощи.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

я хочу имитировать нажатие изображения с помощью vba для получения выгрузки результатов

Если вопрос решён, вы можете выбрать наиболее полезный ответ и принять его. Для этого нужно поставить зелёную галочку слева от ответа.

прощелкайте дальше, получите ссылку на файл выгрузки
https://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/contract/contractCsvSettings/download.html?searchString=%D0%BF%D0%B0&morphology=on&search-filter=%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5+%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F&fz44=on&contractStageList_0=on&contractStageList_1=on&contractStageList_2=on&contractStageList_3=on&contractStageList=0%2C1%2C2%2C3&budgetLevelsIdNameHidden=%7B%7D&sortBy=UPDATE_DATE&pageNumber=1&sortDirection=false&recordsPerPage=_10&showLotsInfoHidden=false&from=1&to=500&numberRegisterContractCsv=true&customerNameCsv=true&customerInnCsv=true&customerKppCsv=true&budgetLavelCsv=true&budgetNameCsv=true&nobudgetViewCsv=true&orderPlanMethodCsv=true&noticeNumberTenderCsv=true&auctionDateCsv=true&requsiteDocumentsCsv=true&contractDateCsv=true&contractNumberCsv=true&contractSubjectNameCsv=true&contractPriceCsv=true&codeBudgetClassificationCsv=true&kosguCsv=true&kvrCsv=true&ikzCsv=true&scopeContractNameServiceCsv=true&scopeContractOkdpCsv=true&scopeContractPriceCsv=true&scopeContractCountCsv=true&scopeContractSumCsv=true&infoSupplierNameCsv=true&infoSupplierInnCsv=true&infoSupplierKppCsv=true&lastDateChangeCsv=true&dateContractCsv=true

меняйте from=1, to=500 и searchString=%D0%BF%D0%B0, search-filter=%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5+%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

огромное спасибо
